# Global function call from function in unnamed namespace with the same name

Tags: c++

I have a some code.
file1.cpp:

```
extern void callout();

int answer() {
    return 5;
}

int main(){
    callout();

    return 0;
}
```

file2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

namespace {
    int answer() {
        cout << ::answer() << endl;
        return 12;
    }
}

void callout() {
    cout << answer() << endl;
}
```

Instead of calling the global `answer()` function, the `answer()` function in unnamed namespace is calls itself recursively, resulting in a stack overflow. How do I call the global `answer()` function from `answer()` function in unnamed namespace?

Comment: Declare it.  Like you did with `callout()`.  file2.cpp has no way of knowing about functions that you may have defined in other files unless you declare them.

Comment: maybe there is a reason to have such weird setup, but I'd invest my time to modify the code so there are not 2 different functions with the same name but in different namespaces. Complier can get rid of it easily, just following its rules. for the poor developper that will need to understand the code next time it will not be so easy

Comment: @DrewDormann
If I add `extern int answer();` in file2.cpp I'll get a error `call of overloaded answer()`, what I agree with.
So I want to call `answer()` from an unnamed namespace first, and then call the global `answer()` function from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to call a function, it needs to be declared in the translation unit. The `answer` function from `file1.cpp` is currently not declared in `file2.cpp`'s translation unit.

To fix this add a header file included in both `.cpp` files containing

```
int answer();
```

(By the way: `extern` on a function declaration is pretty much useless)

With this, the *qualified* call `::answer()` should work as you want it to, calling the overload in the global namespace.

Unfortunately, as you noted in the comments, it will result in the *unqualified* call `answer()` in `callout` failing. This is because an unnamed namespace behaves as if the `using namespace /* unnamed namespace name */;` was used and unqualified name lookup will consider both the overload in a namespace as well as the overload introduced "as if" part of the namespace due to a using-directive equally.

I don't think there is any way to call the `answer` inside the unnamed namespace from outside of it under these circumstances. You can't differentiate the functions by overload resolution and you can't select the one inside the unnamed namespace by name, since the unnamed namespace doesn't have a name you can refer to. Your best option is to rename `answer` in `file2.cpp` or to add a function in the unnamed namespace with a different name forwarding the call to `answer`. Inside the unnamed namespace a simple unqualified call `answer()` will call the function in the unnamed namespace and will not consider the global namespace scope.

All of this would be easier if you didn't use (only) an unnamed namespace. If there was a named namespace differentiating the two functions, either could be called by qualified name.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to fix this problem. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!